# View AWS Glue job logs with CLI

Tags: aws-cli

The [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/index.html#cli-aws-glue) is very good for managing AWS Glue jobs. But if a job fails, I may not see anything more useful than something like:

```
            "JobRunState": "FAILED",
            "ErrorMessage": "User application exited with status 10",
```

And I have to go through the mountain of CloudWatch logs hoping to find something useful. Would appreciate any ideas on getting all logs through the CLI so I can use things like `grep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this question while looking for the answer myself. The following command gets the logs for the last job,

```sh
JOB_ID=$(aws glue get-job-runs --job-name $JOB_NAME --query 'JobRuns[0].Id' --output text)
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name /aws-glue/jobs/output --log-stream-name $JOB_ID
```

Where `$JOB_NAME` is the name of your Glue job. You can also use the log group name `/aws-glue/jobs/error` to see messages written to `stderr` though I've found `/output` more useful.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! The first expression to get the job ID is quite complex and will sometimes produce an error because the query can return multiple comma separated job IDs. I would just use something like `aws glue get-job-runs --job-name $my_job_name --region eu-central-1 | head` to see the latest job run status and ID.

Comment: Yes the `error` output isn't very useful, used it retrospectively on a failed job run for which I had already found the cause, to see if it would have provided a clue, but there are too many unhelpful entries there. The thing is `output` is not available if the job failed early, as it was in this case. I guess finding the needle in the error haystack is an art.